# Creating a GroupBy query to include a result for when no results match

Tags: postgresql, query

Let's say I need a query to see sales results by Month and I want the result-set to include results for each month whether there were any sales in that month or not.

And let's say my table "sales" has the columns "sales_date" and "sales_amount" and I want a result-set to look like:

Jan, 100.00
Feb, 240.00
Mar, 0.00
Apr, 430.00

So, if I want to sum the values by month and there aren't any records for Mar, I still want to see a result for Mar that's 0.  How would I do that?

Comment: What version of postgres?

Answer (score 8):

The usual way to get a series in postgres is with [generate_series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-srf.html). This function produces a series of integers or timestamps - you can use either but assuming your 'dates' are really `timestamptz`, here's how you might go about it if you are on 8.4 or above:

testbed:

```
create table sales(sales_date timestamptz, sales_amount numeric);
insert into sales(sales_date, sales_amount) values('2011-01-15 12:00', 100);
insert into sales(sales_date, sales_amount) values('2011-02-15 12:00', 240);
insert into sales(sales_date, sales_amount) values('2011-04-15 12:00', 400);
insert into sales(sales_date, sales_amount) values('2011-04-16 12:00', 30);
```

query:

```
with w as ( select month, sum(sales_amount) as total
            from (select date_trunc('month',sales_date) as month, sales_amount from sales) z
            group by month )
select to_char(month, 'fmMon') as month, coalesce(total, 0) as total
from (select generate_series(min(month), max(month), '1 month'::interval) as month from w) m
     left outer join w using(month);
```

result:

```
 month | total
-------+-------
 Jan   |   100
 Feb   |   240
 Mar   |     0
 Apr   |   430
```

--edit: a bit of extra detail on the query:

- produce a summary of sales by month (but no month present if no sales):

  ```
  with w as ( select month, sum(sales_amount) as total
              from ( select date_trunc('month',sales_date) as month, sales_amount
                     from sales ) z
              group by month )
  ```

  which could alternatively be written as:

  ```
  with w as ( select date_trunc('month',sales_date) as month, sum(sales_amount) as total
              from sales
              group by date_trunc('month',sales_date) )
  ```
- produce an unbroken series of months (without sales) from the minimum to the maximum:

  ```
  select generate_series(min(month), max(month), '1 month'::interval) as month from w
  ```
- outer join the unbroken series to the summary of sales by month to produce an unbroken series with sales (or `null` sales if no sales present):

  ```
  left outer join w using(month)
  ```
- for the months with `null` sales, change the `null` to a `0`:

  ```
  coalesce(total, 0)
  ```

Comment: Having a list of months is one aspect to the solution. I think you should draw more attention to the `left join` and the `coalesce` function.

Comment: Is that better do you think?

Comment: Yes. I think it is a great answer. Is there any reason you used a CTE over a subquery, or decided to pull out the sum/group by query instead of the generated series of months?

Comment: The CTE is used twice so seemed better than 2 subqueries. The generated series could also be pulled out into a CTE but as it is only used once I favour the subquery - which is just a personal preference because I find choosing names for CTEs harder than it ought to be. 'w' is fine if there is only one :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to outer-join a query that calculates the actual sums to a query that generates a dummy row for each month, using the month as the join key.

Here is how I would do it in Oracle using CONNECT BY LEVEL:

```
select foo.monthdate
     , bar.amount_sum
  from (select add_months(to_date('01-JAN-2011'),level-1) as MONTHDATE
          from dual
        connect by level <= 8
       ) foo
     , (select trunc(sale_date,'MM') as SALE_MONTH
             , sum(amount) as AMOUNT_SUM
          from sales
         where sale_date >= '01-JAN-2011'
           and sale_date <  '01-SEP-2011'
         group by trunc(sale_date,'MM')
       ) bar
 where foo.monthdate = bar.sale_month(+)
 order by foo.monthdate
```

Unfortunately there's no simple translation of CONNECT BY LEVEL to Postgres (edit: apparently there is, see Jack Douglas' answer), but a simple alternative is to construct a date dimension table...

```
create table date_dim
(
  date_id number
, daydate date
, week_begin date
, month_begin date
, year number 
, month number 
, day_of_month number
, day_of_year number
--et cetera...
);
```

...and populate that table with every date for a hundred years in both directions.  Then you can generate the dates you need very simply (converting dates to spelled-out months left as an exercise for the reader):

```
select daydate
  from date_dim
 where daydate >= '01-JAN-2011'
   and daydate <  '01-SEP-2011'
   and day_of_month = 1
```